# iOS - in app with SFSafariViewController unable to load another host in iframe

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying to load the host1 page, it contains iframe and the URL for the iframe is host2. But iframe with URL host2 is not loading properly.

I am loading host1 page through `SFSafariViewController`. If I load the same thing with the iPhone safari browser then it is working fine but not working with `SFSafariViewController`. As per my understanding, `WKWebview` has some limitations but `SFSafariViewController` doesn't have but still facing the issue.

I have tried the below options also in iOS14.5.1 but still, it is not working:

- Enabled `Allow Cross-Website Tracking` by using `NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription` in info.plist
- Enabled `Allow Tracking` by using `Privacy - Tracking Usage Description` in info.plist
- used `WKAppBoundDomains` also.

am I missing anything, please help me out?

**Adding few more details:**

When I am inspecting the code got the below errors with the mobile app `SFSafariViewCotroller` and the required content is not loading, but it is working fine with mobile, desktop Safari browsers and not showing any errors.

- Refused to load {URL://**_csrfRefresh**=1} because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.
- Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at {URL} from accessing a cross-origin frame. Ther being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag

Attaching a screenshot below for reference,

[image]